# Multiple Data Source using Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am building a stand alone java application using Spring JPA frame
work.  I am able to access the DB in below scenario: if I give the
DB details in application.properties file as

```
spring.datasource.url=******** spring.datasource.username=******
spring.datasource.password=******
```

then it's working properly.

but I have to create two DB connections in the same application so,
I changes the names as below

```
spring.Datasource1.url=********* spring.Datasource1.username=******
spring.Datasource1.password

spring.Datasource2.url=************ spring.Datasource2.username=****
spring.Datasource2.password=*****
```

then it's not working.

Can you please provide the solution for it?

I have uploaded my code base in below location.
https://github.com/nagtej/MultipleDataSource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be helpful to you http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

Also, to connect to multiple data sources you would need to manually configure a `DataSource`, `EntityManagerFactory` and `JpaTransactionManager`.

For this, you can have a look at code placed at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources

Another good example for this is shared at http://xantorohara.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/spring-boot-jdbc-with-multiple.html

Comment: instead of links I suggest you give the answer a bit more body, link only answers aren't encouraged.

Comment: Thanq So  much for your answer. it fix my problem. here i have doubt that, when we are using multiple data source, how the repository will know to which DB it need to connect. Can you please me tell me that.